# Sim contacts on call screen?

Tags: contacts, sim-card, caller-id

Is it possible to see contacts from SIM on the incoming call screen and in SMS messages? I did only find apps for managing them.
I am using Cyanogen 7.2 (that’s Android 2.3.7) if that matters.

NOTE: I am not interested in paid apps.

Answer (score -1):

"SIM Contacts" by "NEEDOM STUDIO" is a free app on the Android market that shows contacts from SIM on the incoming call screen. You have to enable the "incoming calls to remind" option for this.

I didn't find an app that shows them in the SMS or call log. I'd really like that.

Even better would be just an option in a normal contacts manager to include contacts on the SIM without having to copy them to the phone.

I like to keep my contacts on the SIM only so i can just put my SIM in my old phone (with longer battery life) and it shows all the contacts.